# Trying to integrate the mmenu.js(off canvas menu) into my site, having trouble with my sticky footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mmenu

I'm trying to add a off canvas menu into my site and the one I picked was the mmenu(http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/index.php). Everything else other then my footer works. I have a sticky footer in the site and every time the menu is clicked open the footer flys out of position.

For a fixed footer, add the class mm-fixed-bottom:
id="footer" class="mm-fixed-bottom">Goodbye<

```
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/1eddy87/Lx5ps/1/
```

I have tried the documented way which says you should use "mm-fixed-bottom" for any fixed elements, however that didn't do the trick.

```
Documentation: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/tutorial.php
```

scroll to the bottom of the page and then open the menu via the header and you will see the footer move out of position.

any ideas??

I realize that I am using absolute, and not fixed. Its a requirement for the sticky footer(http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/). I tried to fix my way through hoping that the mm-fixed-bottom would work, however it didn't. I need a fix for using the absolute.

Answer (score 0):

You've got `position:absolute` on the footer when it's supposed to be `fixed`. You're also overwriting the CSS from `mm-fixed-bottom`. I thought the whole reason for a sticky footer is for it to stay at the bottom of the screen and not move.

I removed all positioning and it worked.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lx5ps/3/

---

Solution found:

On further inspection, looks like the library changes `<div class="mm-page">` to `height:100%` which screws with `height:auto`. I toggled it off in browser inspector and it works.

Changed this:

```
html.mm-opened .mm-page {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lx5ps/4/

Comment: the reason I was using that code is because its a sticky footer not a fixed footer see example http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/. I realize that I am using absolute, and not fixed. Its a requirement for the sticky footer. I tried to fix my way through hoping that the mm-fixed-bottom would work, however it didn't. I need a fix for using the absolute. Sorry should have mentioned that above

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought that using the word sticky means it needs to stick there. The one your referring to is if the content doesn't push the footer to the bottom, it will align there. mm-fixed-bottom has position:fixed in it.

Answer (score 0):

Just been having the same problem but I came up with using css calc.

```
html.mm-opened .mm-page {
height: -webkit-calc(100% - 320px);
height: -moz-calc(100% - 320px);
height: calc(100% - 320px);}
```

320px being the height of the footer. Calc is pretty well supported. See [calc browser support](http://caniuse.com/calc)